# Splitting a sequence of number into a list (Python)

Tags: string, list, split, integer, enumerate

I wanted to ask you how can I split in Python for example this string '20020050055' into a list of integer that looks like [200, 200, 500, 5, 5].

I was thinking about enumerate but do you have any example of a better solution to accomplish this example? thanks

Comment: What is your programming language?

Comment: Python language

Comment: What is the splitting logic?  Non zero digits followed by optional zeroes?  Something else?

Comment: yeah for example if I have a string '2000202002' i want to show out a list with [2000,20,200,2] so every time there is a zero sequence it will be part of the number(from 1 to 9) on the left .

Comment: another example string '9005720400' show out a list [900,5,7,20,400]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach, using a regex find all:

```py
inp = '20020050055'
matches = re.findall(r'[1-9]0*', inp)
print(matches)  # ['200', '200', '500', '5', '5']
```

If, for some reason, you *can't* use regular expressions, here is an iterative approach:

```py
inp = '20020050055'
matches = []
num = ''
for i in inp:
    if i != '0':
        if num != '':
            matches.append(num)
        num = i
    else:
        num = num + i
matches.append(num)

print(matches)   # ['200', '200', '500', '5', '5']
```

The idea here is to build out each match one digit at a time.  When we encounter a non zero digit, we start a new match.  For zeroes, we keep concatenating them until reaching the end of the input or the next non zero digit.

Comment: another solution without importing new libraries? I want a method without importing re module

Comment: Honestly `re.findall` is very well suited for this task.  I think other solutions would be much uglier.  Why do you not want to use regex?

Comment: Because its a course test where they asked me to split a sequence of number in a string into a list of integer where if the string is '200565102' it show out a list with [200,5,6,5,10,2] . I was thinking about enumerate method maybe?

Comment: I have also given you an iterative approach.